# How to display date with Arabic numbers in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to display numbers in Arabic in a report developed in SSRS. I am able to display numbers such as 23000.00 in Arabic by setting the **Language** property to "ar-SA" and **NumeralVariant** to 3. However this doesn't work for TextBox that display date in the format dd/MM/yyyy.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the output/format you are expecting for users here that aren't familiar with Arabic date formats?

Comment: I need to show the date 31/12/2017 as ٣١/١٢/٢٠١٧

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there isn't a built in way to do this, so you have to do it manually in your dataset query.  I would recommend returning both a `date` type and your Arabic date as a `nvarchar` to retain filtering and ease of date logic.  If you cannot be bothered to use the below on all your dates you could wrap the replace logic into a function:

```
declare @d date = '20171231';

select @d as DateValue

    ,convert(nvarchar(10), @d,103) as StringValue

    ,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
        convert(nvarchar(10), @d,103)
        ,'0',N'٠')
        ,'1',N'١')
        ,'2',N'٢')
        ,'3',N'٣')
        ,'4',N'٤')
        ,'5',N'٥')
        ,'6',N'٦')
        ,'7',N'٧')
        ,'8',N'٨')
        ,'9',N'٩') as ArabicValue
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| DateValue  | StringValue | ArabicValue |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2017-12-31 | 31/12/2017  | ٣١/١٢/٢٠١٧ |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the following function in the SSRS report.

```
Public Function ToArabicNumber(input As String) As String
    Dim output As String

    output = input.Replace("1","١")
    output = output.Replace("2","٢")
    output = output.Replace("3","٣")
    output = output.Replace("4","٤")
    output = output.Replace("5","٥")
    output = output.Replace("6","٦")
    output = output.Replace("7","٧")
    output = output.Replace("8","٨")
    output = output.Replace("9","٩")
    output = output.Replace("0","٠")

    Return output
End Function
```

And consume in the report using expression as follows

```
=Code.ToArabicNumber(Format(DateTime.Today,"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```